# Change pivot table from Series to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 
                   'B': ['X', 'Y', 'Z'] * 3, 
                   'C': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  X  1
1  1  Y  2
2  1  Z  3
3  2  X  1
4  2  Y  2
5  2  Z  3
6  3  X  1
7  3  Y  2
8  3  Z  3

result = df.pivot_table(index=['B'], values='C', aggfunc=sum)
>>> result
B
X    3
Y    6
Z    9
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

How can I have the column name for C show up a above the sums, and how can I sort result either ascending or descending.  Result is a series not a dataframe and seems non-sortable?

Python: 2.7.11 and Pandas: 0.17.1

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Note that the brackets around the values coerces the result into a dataframe instead of a series (i.e. `values=['C']` instead of `values='C'`).

```
result = df.pivot_table(index = ['B'], values=['C'], aggfunc=sum)

>>> result
   C
B   
X  3
Y  6
Z  9
```

As`result` is now a dataframe, you can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) on it:

```
>>> result.sort_values('C', ascending=False)
   C
B   
Z  9
Y  6
X  3
```

Comment: How would you sort either in ascending or descending order?

Comment: `ascending=True` or `ascending=False`